Custom ACF field type don't save in Gutenberg
I'm trying to create my own custom field type in ACF called "Code Field" that will format CSS, HTML, and JS using Ace.
My code:
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

class PREFIX_acf_field_code_field extends \acf_field {
    public $show_in_rest = true;
    private $env;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'code';
        $this->label = __('Code', 'behold-helpers');
        $this->category = 'content';
        $this->description = __('Code field for CSS, HTML and JavaScript', 'behold-helpers');
        $this->doc_url = 'FIELD_DOC_URL';
        $this->tutorial_url = 'FIELD_TUTORIAL_URL';
        $this->defaults = array(
            'language'  => 'html',
            'theme'     => 'github',
        );
        $this->l10n = array(
            'error' => __('Error! Please enter a higher value', 'behold-helepers'),
        );
        $this->env = array(
            'url'     => site_url(str_replace(ABSPATH, '', __DIR__)),
            'version' => '1.0',
        );
        $this->preview_image = $this->env['url'] . '/assets/images/field-preview-custom.png';
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function render_field_settings($field) {
        acf_render_field_setting($field, [
            'label'             => __('Language', 'acf-code'),
            'instructions'      => __('Language to use for highlighting.', 'acf-code'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'name'              => 'language',
            'choices'           => [
                'css'          => __('CSS', 'acf-code'),
                'html'         => __('HTML', 'acf-code'),
                'javascript'   => __('JavaScript', 'acf-code'),
                'json'         => __('JSON', 'acf-code'),
                'php'          => __('PHP', 'acf-code'),
                'svg'          => __('SVG', 'acf-code'),
                'text'         => __('Text', 'acf-code'),
            ],
        ]);

        acf_render_field_setting($field, [
            'label'             => __('Theme', 'acf-code'),
            'instructions'      => __('Theme to use for highlighting.', 'acf-code'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'name'              => 'theme',
            'choices'           => [
                __('Light', 'acf-code') => [
                    // some code
                ],
                __('Dark', 'acf-code') => [
                    // some code
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function render_field($field) {
        ?>
        <textarea class="hidden" name="<?= esc_attr($field['name']) ?>" data-language="<?= $field['language']; ?>" data-theme="<?= $field['theme']; ?>"></textarea>
        <div class="editor" style="width: 100%;"><?= esc_html($field['value']); ?></div>
        <?php
    }

    public function input_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_register_style('ace-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ace-builds@1.32.9/css/ace.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('ace-css');
        wp_register_script('ace', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js');
        wp_register_script('acf-input-code', '' . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/assets/js/field.js', ['ace']);
        wp_enqueue_script('acf-input-code');
    }
}


Everything works fine until it comes to saving the field properties. Saving works in the classic editor, but not in Gutenberg. I created the file based on this example: https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf-example-field-type.
Any advice?
